# Modify View Controller Property from Delegate Method

Tags: swift, delegates, viewcontroller, subview

I'm using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.2.

I created a custom alert which is a `UIViewController` called `DialAlert`.  It overlays on top of the current `UIViewController` and has two buttons, `Call` and `Cancel`.

When `Call` is tapped, I report the tap to the underlying viewcontroller with a delegate method called `callTapped.`  That method performs call setup using various other methods.  While it is performing call setup, I would like to update the `DialAlert` viewcontroller with the status.  But I can't access its properties from `callTapped`, the delegate method, because it was created in a tableView method as follows:

```
let dialAlert = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.dialAlert) as! DialAlert
```

And it is in this tableView method that I set all its initial properties.

I tried this code at the beginning of the class:

```
var dialAlert = UIViewController() as! DialAlert
```

and then referenced self.dialAlert throughout the code (which did compile), but at runtime I get an error that I can't cast value of type `UIViewController` to `DialAlert`.

How can I modify the properties of `dialAlert` in a method outside of the one in which the instance was created?  I found some answers in SO that looked promising, but nothing recent and nothing on point.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for your issues, I don't know how you code to show your `DialAlert`, but as per mine your can understand how to implement it.

So, first of all in **AppDelegate.swift** method add following code.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    static var shared  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    .....
    .....
}
```

Thereafter, inside your dialog alert declare protocol and create delegate, apart from that check delegate and call delegate method on button clicked.

**DialAlertVC.swift**

```
protocol DialAlertVCDelegate: class {
    func callButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
}


class DialAlertVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dialAlertView: UIView!

    weak var delegate   : DialAlertVCDelegate?

    class func viewController() -> DialAlertVC {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DialAlertVC") as! DialAlertVC
    }

    @IBAction func btnCallTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let selfDelegate = self.delegate {
            selfDelegate.callButtonTapped(sender)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btnCancelTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if let selfDelegate = self.delegate {
            selfDelegate.cancelButtonTapped(sender)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Now, it's time to show/hide `DialoAlertVC`, so inside `ViewController` add following code.

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblButtonTapped: UILabel!

    var dialAlertVC         : DialAlertVC?

    @IBAction func btnShowDialAlert(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.showDialAlert(true)
    }

    func showDialAlert(_ show: Bool) {

        if show {

            if self.dialAlertVC != nil {
                self.dialAlertVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.dialAlertVC = nil
            }

            dialAlertVC = DialAlertVC.viewController()
            dialAlertVC?.delegate = self
            AppDelegate.shared.window?.addSubview(dialAlertVC!.view)

        } else {

            if self.dialAlertVC != nil {
                self.dialAlertVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.dialAlertVC = nil
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController: DialAlertVCDelegate {

    func callButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.showDialAlert(false)
        self.lblButtonTapped.text = "Call Button Tapped"
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.showDialAlert(false)
        self.lblButtonTapped.text = "Cancel Button Tapped"
    }
}
```

See demo project here: https://gofile.io/?c=P2VKCl

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This looks like a good approach.  I will try it and post back.  Thanks!